# Why do I see an exclamation mark still?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

This morning I recreated from scratch my repositories for my solutions and did an initial commit for each to my Bitbucket account.

But I still get a exclamation mark showing:

[image: Exclamation]

[image: Exclamation]

When I right-click in the repository and choose **Check for modifications** nothing shows up.

### Update

On closer inspection I have found that these folders are the ones that have exclamation marks on the files:

```
D:\My Programs\2017\MeetSchedAssist\Meeting Schedule Assistant\x64\Release\Meeting .56FC3877.tlog
D:\My Programs\2017\MeetSchedAssist\Meeting Schedule Assistant\x64\Debug\Meeting .56FC3877.tlog
```

I start with that project. This is my `gitignore` file:

```
/Volunteer MWB Data/MWBDataUpdate.zip
/Inno/BuildLogHelp.txt
/Inno/BuildLogInnoSetup.txt
/.vs

## Build Folders (you can keep bin if you'd like, to store dlls and pdbs)
# [Bb]in/
[Oo]bj/

# mstest test results
TestResults

## Ignore Visual Studio temporary files, build results, and
## files generated by popular Visual Studio add-ons.

# User-specific files
*.suo
*.user
*.sln.docstates

# Build results
[Dd]ebug/
[Rr]elease/
x64/
*_i.c
*_p.c
*.ilk
*.meta
*.obj
*.pch
*.pdb
*.pgc
*.pgd
*.rsp
*.sbr
*.tlb
*.tli
*.tlh
*.tmp
*.log
*.vspscc
*.vssscc
.builds

# Visual C++ cache files
ipch/
*.aps
*.ncb
*.opensdf
*.sdf

# Visual Studio profiler
*.psess
*.vsp
*.vspx
```

The second project shows the issue here:

```
D:\My Programs\2017\DatabaseUtility\bin\x86\Debug\DatabaseUtility.exe.config
```

The third project shows the issue here:

```
D:\My Programs\2017\GoogleAuthandSync\GoogleAuthandSync\bin\Debug
```

There are various files in the above folder - xml | dll | config.

Each repository has it's own `gitignore` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The status for files/folders are cached by default. This cache can sometimes be a bit behind (and is currently under optimization in development).

Solutions:

1. Open the commit dialog, this normally causes the cache to be invalidated.
2. Create and then delete a file, this causes the cache to be invalidated.
3. Deactivate the cache (not recommended) in TortoiseGit settings, icon overlay and choose "Shell exteneded" or "Shell cache" there (cf. https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html#tgit-dug-settings-overlay)

Update: This especially is related to ignored files where the ignore list is also cached and often only reloaded when the cache is invalidated.

Comment: Thanks. Please see my updated question. I have tried 1 and 2. Don't seem to work.

Comment: In the first scenario, the files are in the ignore files section and I can see them listed if I tick to show ignored files. This seems like I have to do option 3. But you put "not recommended".

Comment: Setting it to "Shell extended" works. But if I switch it back to "Default" the exclamation shows again.

Comment: Will I be able to set it back to `Default`?

Comment: "Default" means that the TGitCache process is used - as it's the default it is the recommended way and should work :). When TGitCache is gracefully ended it stores its cache to disk - try to kill the process in order to make it re-load all data. Please try the latest [preview release](https://download.tortoisegit.org/tgit/previews/), there were some fixes/improvements to TGitCache.